# Rails address book

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, json, ruby

Hi i'm abit of a noob and i'd appreciate any help with this. I am trying to use the data a user saved into their address book, after which I would like to give them the option of using the address for delivery.

Here is my Address controller

```
class AddressesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_address, only: [ :show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /addresses
  # GET /addresses.json
  def index
    @addresses = current_user.addresses.all
  end

  # GET /addresses/1
  # GET /addresses/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /addresses/new
  def new
    @address = current_user.addresses.build
  end

  # GET /addresses/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /addresses
  # POST /addresses.json
  def create
    @address = current_user.addresses.build(address_params)
    @address = current_user 

    respond_to do |format|
      if @address.save
        format.html { redirect_to addresses_url, notice: 'Address was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @address }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @address.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /addresses/1
  # PATCH/PUT /addresses/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @address.update(address_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @address, notice: 'Address was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @address }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @address.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /addresses/1
  # DELETE /addresses/1.json
  def destroy
    @address.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to addresses_url, notice: 'Address was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_address
      @address = Address.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
    def address_params
      params.require(:address).permit(:address, :latitude, :longitude)
    end
end
```

and my address form, this uses a google maps api to get a users long and lat

```
  <%= simple_form_for(@address) do |f| %>
    <p class="text-danger" style="width: 500px;">Your address will only be used for deliveries. This is mainly for locating unknown land marks like a household not for use of well known companies or easily locatable land marks. Eg "Little Bay Peer". Mobile users may allow location as it will be more accurate, users on a computer should use the map.</p>

    <div class="form-inputs" style="width: 500px">
      <%= f.input :address %>
      <%= f.input :latitude, id: "address_latitude" %>
      <%= f.input :longitude, id: "address_longitude" %>
    </div>
    <em>Please use the zoom button while redirecting the marker to the exact location you want your delivery </em>
    <p>
      <div id="map2" ></div>
    </p>

    <div class="form-actions">
      <%= f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-success" %><br><br>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Here is where where i'm unsure about
this is my already order controller

```
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_already_order, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  # GET /already_orders
  # GET /already_orders.json
  def index
    @already_orders = current_user.already_orders.order('created_at desc')
  end

  # GET /already_orders/1
  # GET /already_orders/1.json
  def show
  end
 

  # GET /already_orders/new
  def new
    @already_order = current_user.already_orders.build
  end

  # GET /already_orders/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /already_orders
  # POST /already_orders.json
  def create
    @already_order = current_user.already_orders.build(already_order_params)
    @already_order = current_user
    respond_to do |format|
      if @already_order.save
        format.html { redirect_to already_orders_url , notice: 'Already order was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @already_order }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @already_order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /already_orders/1
  # PATCH/PUT /already_orders/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @already_order.update(already_order_params)
        format.html { redirect_to already_orders_url, notice: 'Already order was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @already_order }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @already_order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /already_orders/1
  # DELETE /already_orders/1.json
  def destroy
    @already_order.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to already_orders_url, notice: 'Already order was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_already_order
      @already_order = AlreadyOrder.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
    def already_order_params
      params.require(:already_order).permit(:shop_name, 
        :pick_up_time, 
        :shop_address, 
        :shop_district, 
        :delivery_time, 
        :item_type, 
        :item_cost, 
        :item_quantity, 
        :name, 
        :address, 
        :district, 
        :building, 
        :phone_number, 
        :specific_instructions, 
        :payment_method, 
        :cost,
        :deliver_id,
        :payment_status,
        :specify_delivery_time,
        :paid_for,
        :discount_code,
        :delivery_status,
        :cost_usd)
    end
end
```

This is my already order form

```
<%= form_for(@already_order) do |f| %>  
<div class="row p-3 pt-5">
    <div class="col-md-8 order-md-1">
       <h3 class="mb-3 text-muted">Pickup Details</h3>
        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="form-group form-group col-md-6">
            <label>Business name</label>
            <%= f.hidden_field :deliver_id, value: SecureRandom.hex(5) %>
            <%= f.hidden_field :payment_status, value: "Pending" %>
            <%= f.hidden_field :delivery_status %>
            <%= f.text_field :shop_name, class:"form-control", placeholder: "Grand Phenix", required: true %>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label>Business address</label>
            <%= f.text_field :shop_address, class:"form-control", placeholder: "Brades", required: true %>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-9">
            <label>Business district</label><em style="font-size: 12px;">  if business district and delivery district are diffrent you will be charged $4</em>
            <%= f.select :shop_district, ['','Cojoehead - Sweenyes', "St. John's - Look Out" , 'Cheapend - Salem'], {}, { :class => 'form-control', :id => 'dist1', :onchange => 'addto()' } %>
          </div>  
          <div class="form-group col-md-3">
            <%= f.label :pick_up_time %>
            <div class="form-inline">
              <%= f.datetime_select :pick_up_time, { ampm: true, order: [:hour, :minute] }, { class:"form-control", :required => true } %>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-5">
            <label>Address</label>
            <%= f.select("address", Address.all.collect {|p| [ p.address ] },{}, { :class => 'form-control' })%>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-5">
            <label>Item Type</label>
            <%= f.select :item_type, ['','Food & Drinks', "Groceries" , 'Packages'], {}, { :class => 'form-control', :id => 'sitem', :onchange => 'addto()' } %>
          </div>
          <p id="item_cost"></p>
          <p id="dis_cost"></p>
          <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <label>Item Quantity or Weight in lbs</label>
            <%= f.number_field :item_quantity, class: 'form-control' , id:'weight', :onchange => 'addto()' %>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-3">
            <%= f.label :delivery_time %>
            <div class="form-inline">
              <%= f.select :delivery_time, ['8:00 am', '11:50 am', '3:00 pm', '7:30 pm'], {}, { :class => 'form-control' } %>
            </div>
          </div>  
        </div><br><br><br>
        
        <h3 class="text-muted">Delivery Details </h3>
        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="form-group col-md-5">
            <%= f.label :name %>
            <%= f.text_field :name, class:"form-control", placeholder: "John Browne", required: true %>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-5">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <%= f.label :building %>
            <%= f.text_field :building, class:"form-control", placeholder: "Third house on the right", required: true %>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-10">
            <%= f.label :district %><em style="font-size: 12px;">  if delivery district and shop district are diffrent you will be charged $4</em>
            <%= f.select :district, ['','Cojoehead - Sweenyes', "St. John's - Look Out" , 'Cheapend - Salem'], {}, { :class => 'form-control', :id => 'dist2', :onchange => 'addto()' } %>
          </div> 
          <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <%= f.label :phone_number %>
            <%= f.number_field :phone_number, class:"form-control", placeholder: "393-0000", required: true %>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-10">
            <%= f.label :specific_instructions %>
            <%= f.text_area :specific_instructions, class:"form-control", placeholder: "Knock on the pink door downstairs and deliver it to Tim Browne ", :size => "24x6", :required => true %>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Button trigger modal -->
        <div class="ml-3">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" required>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#staticBackdrop">
            Terms and Conditions
          </button>
        </div>
        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="staticBackdrop" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="staticBackdropLabel">Instructions and Pricing</h5>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                Please ensure that the Pickup district and delivery district are correct as you will be charged $5 for wrong details.<br><br>
                <div class="mx-2"><strong>Food and Drinks</strong> <br> 
                <em>1 Food and Drink is are a pair as 1</em><br>
                1-2 Food and Drinks = $5 <br>
                3-6 Food and Drinks = $10 <br>
                More and 6 Food and Drinks = $1.6 per <br>
                <strong>Groceries</strong> <br>
                $1.75 per lb <br>
                <strong>Items</strong> <br>
                $2.2 per lb </div><br><br>
                <h5>Paymant options</h5>
                <div class="mx-2"><strong>Already paid</strong> - The item is already paid for and it ready for pick up <br>
                <strong>Pay on arrival</strong> - This only applies for items under $50 where Deliver will pay for the item and apon delivery the amount will be paid back plus a $5 fee  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Understood</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div><br><br>
          
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4 order-md-2 mb-4 text-danger">
      <h4 class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center mb-3">
        <span class="text-muted">Charges</span>
      </h4>
      <ul class="list-group mb-2">
        <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between lh-condensed">
          <p id="pitem"></p>
          <span class="text-muted" id="price"></span>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between lh-condensed">
          <p id="district"></p>
          <span class="text-muted" id="district_cost"></span>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between lh-condensed">
          <p id="payment"></p>
          <span class="text-muted" id="pay_cost"></span>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between lh-condensed">
          <p></p>
          <span class="text-muted"></span>
        </li>
      </ul><br>
      <span class="text-muted">Payment Method</span><br>
      <div>
        <%= f.select :payment_method, ['Paypal/Credit Card', "Pay on Arrival"], {}, { :class => 'form-control', :id => 'pay_opt', :onchange => 'addto()' } %>
      </div><br><br>
      <p id="ttl1"></p>
      <p id="ttl2"></p>
      <p id="ttl3"></p>
      <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between">
        <h5>Total (EC)</h5>
        <%= f.hidden_field :cost, id: "ptotal" %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :cost_usd, id: "usdtotal" %>
        <strong id="end"></strong>
      </li>
      <br>

        
      <div class="input-group">
      <%= f.hidden_field :discount_code, class: 'form-control' %>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Discount code">
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <p  class="btn btn-secondary">Redeem</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :Submit, class: "btn btn-success", id: 'display' %>
  </div> 
  <% end %>
</div>
<p id="pay_val"></p>
<p id="end2"></p>
```

I use this to show the options of the addresses already saved

```
<%= f.select("address", Address.all.collect {|p| [ p.address ] },{}, { :class => 'form-control' })%>
```

But when I submit data I get a Associations miss match error, I also dont think the code is working as i want it to yet as after a order is submitted I would want the associated address name, longitude and latitude to be submitted with it.

My models association is as

```
 class Address < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :already_orders
    has_many :orders
end
```

```
class AlreadyOrder < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    has_one :address
end
```

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

    has_many :already_orders, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :orders, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :addresses, dependent: :destroy

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
end
```

I would appreciate any help in this problem

Answer (score 1):

Taking a stab in the dark here but I think the problem is this:

```
<%= f.select("address", Address.all.collect {|p| [ p.address ] },{}, { :class => 'form-control' })%>
```

The second argument of the select form helper accepts a two-dimensional array.

Right now the array you're giving it translates to this:

```
[['the value of the Address objects address attribute'], ['the value of the Address objects address attribute']]
```

You want the array to look like this:

```
[['the value of the Address objects address attribute', address_object_id], ['the value of the Address objects address attribute', address_object_id]]
```

Rails will iterate over the outer array, and use index 0 of each inner array for the innerText of the HTML option tag. It will use index 1 of each inner array for the value of the HTML option tag.

The fixed version of that line of code would be this:

```
<%= f.select("address", Address.all.collect {|p| [ p.address, p.id ] },{}, { :class => 'form-control' })%>
```

Comment: lool. I had already tried this  but a different error appeared `Address(#110424960) expected, got "1" which is an instance of String(#22281700` this points me to my create method in the address controller